# How can I show 5 numbers per line in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am learning python and I am having a bit of trouble nesting a counter within a while loop. I am wanting to print out the first 100 numbers of the Fibonacci sequence. I got it to do that but I want it to display 5 numbers per line.

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = 354224848179261915075           

while b <= c:    
    print(b)
    a, b = b, a + b
```

Output:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17711 28657 46368 75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040 1346269 2178309 3524578 5702887 9227465 14930352 24157817 39088169 63245986 102334155 165580141 267914296 433494437 701408733 1134903170 1836311903 2971215073 4807526976 7778742049 12586269025 20365011074 32951280099 53316291173 86267571272 139583862445 225851433717 365435296162 591286729879 956722026041 1548008755920 2504730781961 4052739537881 6557470319842 10610209857723 17167680177565 27777890035288 44945570212853 72723460248141 117669030460994 190392490709135 308061521170129 498454011879264 806515533049393 1304969544928657 2111485077978050 3416454622906707 5527939700884757 8944394323791464 14472334024676221 23416728348467685 37889062373143906 61305790721611591 99194853094755497 160500643816367088 259695496911122585 420196140727489673 679891637638612258 1100087778366101931 1779979416004714189 2880067194370816120 4660046610375530309 7540113804746346429 12200160415121876738 19740274219868223167 31940434634990099905 51680708854858323072 83621143489848422977 135301852344706746049 218922995834555169026 354224848179261915075
```

This is also a counter I made:

```
counter = 0
for num in range(0, 100):
    counter += 1
    print(num, end=(" " if counter < 5 else "\n"))
    if counter == 5:
        counter = 0
```

I am just needing to join the two together. I appreciate everyones help!

Comment: You shared 2 loops - how can they be merged? What do you want to have?

Comment: In the second piece of code (counter code) that you have, try printing the fibonacci number, instead of the variable `num`.

Comment: @Tyler, have any of the three answers below helped you? Please mark one as accepted so this question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2):

Use your counter in the same loop:

```py
a = 0
b = 1
c = 354224848179261915075           

counter = 0
while b <= c:    
    print(b, end=(" " if counter < 4 else "\n")
    counter = (counter + 1) % 5
    a, b = b, a + b
```

Output:

```py
1 1 2 3 5
8 13 21 34 55
89 144 233 377 610
987 1597 2584 4181 6765
10946 17711 28657 46368 75025
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
counter = 0
while b <= c:
    counter += 1
    print(b,end=' ')
    a, b = b, a + b

    if counter == 5:
        print('')
        counter = 0
```

Result:

```
1 1 2 3 5
8 13 21 34 55
89 144 233 377 610 etc......
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) to compute the Fibonacci sequence numbers, you could then just call `next()` on it however often you wished.

Here's what I mean:

```
LINES = 10
PER_LINE = 5


def fib():
    """ Iteratively return the Fibonacci sequence numbers, starting from 0. """
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b


seq = fib()
for _ in range(LINES):
    line = ', '.join(str(next(seq)) for _ in range(PER_LINE))
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3
5, 8, 13, 21, 34
55, 89, 144, 233, 377
610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181
6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368
75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229
832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887
9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986
102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733
1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049
```

Comment: I think introducing generators is a bit much to ask of somebody "learning python".

Comment: Using a generator is the cleanest solution, as it correctly separates the logic of generating the sequence and the presentation.

Comment: @blorgon: It's not really that mind-blowing of a concept, as well as an extremely useful feature of Python — and arguably one of the better ways to generate the Fib —so the sooner one is introduced to them the better. ;¬)

Comment: While I completely agree that generators are ideal, I still firmly believe that for somebody that couldn't figure this out and had to post on SO asking for help, asking them to grok generators is counter-productive. I've taught Python professionally for 2 years, I know when to push a student into more advanced territory and this is not one of those times.

Comment: @blorgon: All I'll say it that while I'm not a professional instructor, I do have a fair amount of experience answering questions on this site and don't believe in dumbing-down answers (at least not to the degree you seem to be advocating). Also, as I said earlier, I don't think generators are that difficult or that advanced of a topic anyway.